# how to graphically represent the variance of a multidimensional variable

Tags: variance, data-visualization

I would know which is the best way to plot in 2D the variance of an 8-dimensional variable.
I have tried to do an average (for each vector) of each one of the 8 vector's values, therefore I have performed an 8 to 1 reduction, but I'm not sure whether this kind of procedure is correct.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by "the variance" of an eight-dimensional variable?  Would it be the eight variances of its components, the entire $8\times 8$ variance-covariance matrix, or something else?  And what would be the purpose of your plot: what information is it intended to reveal?

Comment: @whuber I get as result of a matrix _A(i) = 8xN_ a vector _V=8x1_., obtained by _V = Var(A(i))_. How could I represent the variance's distribution for (at example) 100 values of _i_?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of graphic representation greatly depends on your audience and what you are trying to convey.

With an 8-d variable, I usually start with a [matrix plot](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/graphs/graphs-of-pairs-of-variables/matrix-plots/matrix-plot/).

With lower dimensions, a [multi-vari plot](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/applying-statistics-in-quality-projects/using-multi-vari-charts-to-analyze-families-of-variations) is quite useful, and may still be useful if you do a reduction of dimensions.

A [standard deviation plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/dexsdplo.htm) would also help you to convey the variance in each dimension.

Another option would be a [main effects plot](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/modeling-statistics/anova/basics/what-is-a-main-effects-plot/) based upon standard deviation for your variable.

A [block plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/blockplo.htm) of your variable can also be useful, especially if you reduce your dimensions by a few levels.